# NextJS: как подгружать роутинги с сервера?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, next.js

У меня есть следующая задача: клиент хочет на сервере сам переводить роуты. То есть, у меня на сайте 3 языка: `ua, ru, en`. Есть роут: `/news`. Надо сделать, что бы эта страница открывалась и при `/news`, и при `/novini`, и при `/novosti`.

Я нашел решение с помощью `rewrites()`:

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/novini',
                destination: '/news',
            }
            {
                source: '/novosti',
                destination: '/news',
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Все работает, только задача усложнилась тем, что клиент хочет сам прописывать эти роуты. А это значит, что мне надо их как то подтянуть с сервера. Подскажите, можно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: `i18n` -> https://www.google.com/?q=nextjs+i18n -> https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

Comment: @qwabra спасибо за столь "обширный" ответ, но если вы внимательно прочитаете вопрос, то поймете что ваше решение - не решение

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно сделать напрямую с `next config`. Вы можете реализовать данную задачу иными путями, перехватив полностью введенный url на стороне сервера.

Вы можете разобрать это внутри `getInitialProps` (нерекомендуемый метод) - перехватывать запросы, подгружать весь список из бд или иных составляющих, разбирать, перенаправлять, или что-то еще далее делать, таким образом, для каждого пользователя будет работать свой список url при подгруженном с сервера данных.

Вот только с таким решением - да, это возможно.